# Text.setText() not updating text, throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I'm having a bit of trouble with the `Text.setText()` method. It is supposed to set the `String` name as it's value.

The FXML code has the text:

```
              <Text fx:id="airlineName" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Airline Name Goes Here" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="17.0" />
                 </font>
              </Text>
```

Here is a fragment of the java code:

```
 @FXML
 Text airlineName;

 private void loadNewWindow(String resource, Button button) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resource));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

 @FXML
 public void viewAirline() throws IOException {
        loadNewWindow("/main/resources/Airline Page.fxml", viewAirline);
        //some code here, involves Object selected
        String name = selected.name;
        airlineName.setText(name); //This is line 67
        airlineName.setFill(Color.RED);
        System.out.println(airlineName.getText());

    }
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ...
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.GUI.Controller.viewAirline(Controller.java:67)
```

---

The `viewAirline` method was not used in java, but in FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="viewAirline" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#viewAirline" text="View Airline" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
```

It is supposed to be activated whenever a button (similarly named) `viewAirline` is pressed.

This FXML code is a different FXML code referenced in the `viewAirline()` method ("/main/resources/Airline Page.fxml"). The `Text` element is referenced in the `Airline Page.fxml`. All FXML files use the same controller.

Comment: Is this due to a mismatch between `airlineName` and `airlineText`?

Comment: My mistake. There is no mismatch, I wrote the wrong code here. It was `airlineName` in the actual code.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct controller instances? BTW: It would be better, if you'd make the `loadNewWindow` method `static`, since there is no real relationship to your controller instance (except maybe the fxml uses the containing class as it's controller class too).

Comment: I am with @fabian: it came to my mind that the FXML injection is not in the controller which are referenced in the FXML file defining it.

Comment: @fabian: I can't make it static. The `getClass()` from `FXMLLoader.load(getClass()...` cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: You can get a reference to the `Class` using `ControllerClass.class` as well... Please show us where the `viewAirline` method is used. Make sure to point out, whether it's in the same fxml file as the `<Text>` element or not (or how the point in the code is related to the fxml, should it be called from java code)...

Comment: @fabian I updated the post with the details.

Comment: replace selected.name with a literal string like "hello world" to see if selected.name is null or not;

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I have. It still throws that exception. It really is the `Text` object that seems to be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the controller class in the fxml file using the `fx:controller` attribute, the `FXMLLoader` creates a new instance of the controller during the loading. This leads to the `airlineName` being `null` since that field is injected to **a different instance** of the controller class. To use the same controller instance, you need to set the controller before loading the fxml file and also remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the fxml file:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlURL);
loader.setController(controllerInstance);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

However I wouldn't recommend using the same controller for multiple fxmls. This leads to a high coupling and changes in the controller or one fxml files may break something in the other fxmls. Especially the `initialize` method would need to take all fxmls into account.

You better use different controllers and make them communicate. You can even program against an interface to avoid relying on a concrete controller class.

You can get the controller instance created by `FXMLLoader` (`fx:controller` attribute present) after calling `load()` using `getController()`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlURL);
Parent root = loader.load();
ControllerClass controller = loader.getController();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. I'm not sure what to modify in the code.

Comment: Assuming you've injected `airlineName` successfully, and kept the `loadNewWindow` method non-`static`, the quick and dirty fix would be using the first snippet in the method with `controllerInstance = this` and `fxmlURL = getClass().getResource(resource)` (+ removing the `fx:controller` attribute from `/main/resources/Airline Page.fxml`).

Answer (score 0):

It might be throwing null pointer exception may be because of the reason that the name attribute in your selected.name is null i.e it is not assigned any value.

Comment: I printed `selected.name`, it is not null. This happens if I remove setText and have setFill instead.

Comment: Put your text defination of airline name at the begining of class only !!

Comment: It is in the beginning of the class. I only provided the relevant portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're not instantiating the `airlineName` object. Try the code below:

```
airlineName = new Text();
airlineName.setText(name);
```

Comment: This removes the exception, however the text is still not updating, nor is it changing in color.

Comment: The field should be injected by the `FXMLLoader`. Assigning the fields value changes the field's value to a `Text` node that is not part of the scene graph...

Comment: @fabian However it throws a `NullPointerException`. The IDE sees the FXML reference, however. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not recognizing the airLine text tag, because the tag is not closed
try to close your text tag:

```
<Text fx:id="airlineName" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Airline Name Goes Here" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
```

OR

```
 <Text fx:id="airlineName" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Airline Name Goes Here" GridPane.rowIndex="1"></Text>
```

Comment: This would yield an error during the loading process. Furthermore it's just a part of the fxml file (imports, namespace declaration are missing too).

Comment: The text tag is closed. I didn't include the rest, but here it is:

                  `<Text fx:id="airlineName" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Airline Name Goes Here" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="17.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>`